# How to effectively use the saw to open deposit boxes and doors?

Tags: payday-2

I've recently unlocked the OVE9000 saw to use and I'm having trouble opening doors and deposit boxes with it. Opening ATM's seems easy.

Is there a trick to opening doors and deposit boxes? Does aiming at the 'lock' make any difference? On a good try I can get maybe 2-3 boxes open before the blade runs out, and on a bad day, I've used a whole blade just to get one box open.

I do not have the Portable Saw Ace, so am stuck, for the meantime, with regular blades; so how I use those blade is paramount to the effectiveness of the saw.

Comment: I thought you mean a M249 :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tips I can give you is to bring 2 bags of ammo along with you aswell for the bank job.
 Also don't place an ammo bag to soon because with the low effectiveness of the saw you are surely going to need it the 2 ammo bags to get through all the lockboxes.
**Edit:** Taking ammo from the ammo bag also refills your blades.

Just set them up and keep on sawing, the saw system is also abit lacking in that you have to aim it correctly to actually open the boxes. You need to aim at the right hand side of the boxes and use the saw like you would use an automatic gun, you need to burst fire. Because any additional hits against anything (in the air you don't lose your 'ammo') will take away the 'ammo' for the saw.

Comment: So your tip for more effective use of the saw is just to take more ammo? Does this really answer the question? Can you rephrase it perhaps?

Comment: @DavidYell No the tip is aim correctly and use burst fire... but more ammo can always help. Basicly aim at where the system is telling you to saw.

Comment: But deposit boxes do not have an actual saw marker, they're just marked with a square box showing the item is sawable. Unless I've misunderstood the markers.

Comment: @DavidYell I always aimed at the markers... seems to do the trick, if you notice the ATM machines I aim at the side aswell, and then the 4 corners.

Answer (score 4):

Click, do not hold. If you hold you could accidentally use the blade once. Two clicks for deposits, about five for doors, and two to open ATMs.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This seems to be sound advice - or is it not?

Answer (score 4):

Just gently tap fire 2 times on deposit boxes and exteriors of ATMs, 5 times on metal doors. Don't waste blades on wooden doors, just shoot the doorknob in, and carry as much ammo as you can, including both the ace of the original skill (allows for one extra blade).

Use the skill above granting 20 percent harder blades (I don't know if the 25 percent extra ammo skill affects saw blades, however). It's really only useful in the bank, personally I reskilled myself in technician. Shaped charges are better for getting through doors and you can carry a gun that actually kills enemies at distance.

Answer (score 4):

I was playing with some players recently who were talking about the "Beserker" skill.
They had stated that by letting their health drop to a quarter, it meant their saw was 3 times as effective. I'll respec eventually and test it. Consider it though. Using it as standard, I found short bursts, and relax.

Comment: I can confirm that this does work, and should be taken advantage of whenever possible. I can open deposit boxes with one click if I have less than 25% health with the [Berserker](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Skills#Enforcer) skill.

Comment: Seconded. This is my standard method for opening boxes. It only takes a single click, and you never even need to put down a second ammo bag.

Answer (score 1):

The [Butcher Mod Pack # 2](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/The_Butcher_Mod_Pack_2) introduces mods for the OVE9000 Saw. Installing the [Fast Motor](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Fast_Motor) and [Sharp Blade](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Sharp_Blade) mods will increase the damage of the saw, nearly doubling its damage. With those mods, even without the Berserker skill, you will be able to open deposit boxes in one click.

---

Another trick is if you have the [Bulletstorm](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Bulletstorm) skill aced. Description of the skill:

> Basic: Ammo bags placed by you grant players the ability to shoot without depleting their ammunition for up to 5 seconds after interacting with it. The more ammo players replenish, the longer the duration of the effect.
>
> Ace:  Increases the base duration of the effect by up to 15 seconds.

To maximize the skill's effect duration, you'll need to empty the ammo of your non-saw weapon (to prolong the skill's duration), and leave the saw with just one magazine left and reloaded (so you'd have a full magazine and have no need to reload after the skill's effect ends*).

Then, deploy the ammo bag and interact with it to activate Bulletstorm's effect. While the skill's effect is active (while your ammo won't be depleted), you just need to hold the fire button (no need to click) to open as many deposit boxes as possible.

<sup>* Only two seconds of ammo non-depletion time will be added if you completely empty the saw.  In exchange, you will have to reload the saw after the effect ends.</sup>

<sup>Source: [Reddit /r/paydaytheheist post by dive_bomber](https://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/71ayxl/bankers_hate_him_discover_how_he_got_rich_with/)</sup>

Comment: This is a great alternative to the method posted by @Brok3n. Personally, I prefer using the _silent motor_ and durable blade with berserker, but depending on the map and tactics, this could suit you better.

Answer (score 1):

1. Aim correctly: to the right side of the safeboxes, where the symbol of their lock is.
2. Use one or two clicks, not a prolonged pressure of the fire button, in order to avoid an excessive consumption of the blades.
3. Proceed starting from the left corner of the vault and going from there to the right direction, so that the door of the opened safes (which opens from the right to the left) cannot interfere with the sawing of the closed ones.
4. Take the ammunition bag, to have new blades to replace the broken ones.
5. Develop, as soon as you can, the skills for the extra blade, the carbon special blades and the increased efficiency of the saw and of the drill inside the skill tree of the Enforcer and of the Technician (so doing you will be able to open a safebox of bank in just 1 click of the fire button and all the safes of Bank Go with your standard number of blades and the safes of the Trusty Bank with one recharge from the ammunition bag).
6. Keep trying: you will do it better each time and you will have real fun opening all these safeboxes and stealing the valuables inside... Have a good robbery, mate!