# How can I quickly open a safe deposit box?

Tags: payday-2

Certain missions require you to open a safe deposit boxes, which take quite a long time to open with a lock pick. I've noticed that there are icons for using a saw and C4 on them, but I haven't unlocked them yet. Is the slow process of lock picking the only way for me to open safe deposit boxes then, or is there a faster method? Perhaps there's a switch or key I can find to open them?

Additionally, assuming their are multiple safe deposit boxes within close proximity of each other, will C4 open several of them or just one?

Comment: Related: [How to effectively use the saw to open deposit boxes and doors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/128790/4797)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only ways to open a safe deposit box are

- picking the lock (can be made faster with *Lockpicking Expert* from Ghost)
- using the saw.

It is worth noting that the saw is a lot quicker, but also a lot noisier.

You **cannot** open the safe deposit boxes with C4. There is no icon for it and the icon is required to place C4.

Comment: are you sure? I could have sworn I saw a C4 symbol when I was playing through. I'll need to check again next time I'm playing.

Comment: @Wipqozn I just checked it in-game and did not see it. Although, I admit it was in Bank Heist: Gold, not in Deposit, *but* I was also unable to find any video/image material of C4 being used in the safe deposit boxes *in Bank Heist: Deposit*. I spent a good 15 minutes looking for it and came up with nothing. Checked the update notes as well - no mention. Please do check next time you play it. I'll check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

Without the C4 or Saw skills (in Technician and Enforcer, respectively), lockpicking is the only way to open security deposit boxes. Without the Lockpicking Expert skill (Ghost), it's 20 seconds to pick a security deposit box. With the basic Lockpicking Expert, this is cut to  17 seconds. With the ace Lockpicking Expert skill, it takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not far in the Technician tree, so I don't know whether C4 opens multiple boxes.

Answer (score 4):

In any version of the game, its impossible to open a SAFETY DEPOSIT BOX with c4. However SMALL SAFES can be opened with c4. Safety deposit boxes are only openable by the saw and lockpicking. You cannot drill safety deposit boxes to clarify only small safes. Anyone that says you can use c4 is mislead and is mistaking small safes for safety deposit boxes also safety deposit boxes line the safe walls to clarify for anyone else that says that you can open them with c4

Answer (score -2):

Well you can use a shaped charge c4 for the Xbox

Comment: I don't think this is the case... but I *could* be wrong. Either way, I know it's not the case in the PC version, and OVERKILL are currently working on getting the patches out to the consoles.